# Lua string.gsub without printing match count

Tags: lua

Frustratingly, any my previous Lua tries went in extensive Google searching of more/less same Lua resources, and then resulted in some multi-line code to get basic things, which i.e. I get from Python with simple command.

Same again, I want to replace substring from string, and use i.e.:

`string.gsub("My string", "str", "th")`

which results in:

> My thing    1

I imagine replacement count can be useful, but who would expect it by default, and without option to suppress it, but maybe I miss something?

How to print just string result, without counter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enclose in parentheses: `(string.gsub("My string", "str", "th"))`.

Comment: Just to make it clearer on why it works - the parentheses around `string.gsub` force the expression into a single value (the first value or **nil**). [See manual for details](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4).

Answer (score 4):

The results are only a problem because you are using `print`, which takes multiple parameters. Lua allows multiple assignments, so normally the code would look like

```
newstr, n = string.gsub("My string", "str", "th")
```

but the count is only provided if there is a place to put it, so

```
newstr = string.gsub("My string", "str", "th")
```

is also fine, and causes the count to be discarded. If you are using `print` directly (the same applies to `return`) then you should enclose the call in parentheses to discard all but the first result.